# creating a unique jquery dialog style for each id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My code:

```
<style>
#demo .ui-dialog-titlebar, #demo .ui-dialog-content {
    font-size: 12px
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#demo').dialog();
});
</script>

<div id="demo" title="sample dialog">blah blah blah</div>
```

My question is...  why isn't the font-size being adjusted with that code? If I do `.ui-dialog-titlebar, .ui-dialog-content` it works just fine. What I don't like about that is that that's applying the style to all jquery dialog windows hence the `#demo .ui-dialog-titlebar, #demo .ui-dialog-content`.

The JS fiddle with `#demo .ui-dialog-titlebar, #demo .ui-dialog-content`:

http://jsfiddle.net/gucu9u75/

And a JS fiddle of it with just `.ui-dialog-titlebar, .ui-dialog-content`:

http://jsfiddle.net/gucu9u75/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initiate a jQuery dialog box it places the given DOM element(#demo) in new parent elements. To get a better idea of how it restructures the DOM element you can inspect the generated html(see screen shot below).

[image: Inspected]

The first part of your CSS, `#demo.ui-dialog-titlebar` is not targeting the title area. You'll see the title element is now a sibling of `#demo`.

The second part, `#demo .ui-dialog-content` assumes `.ui-dialog-content` is a child of `#demo` when the content is in fact the `#demo` element.

One solution ***to be able to target individual dialog boxes in CSS***, just off the top of my head, would be to wrap the dialog box in a parent element yourself:

```
<style>
#demo-wrapper .ui-dialog-titlebar, #demo-wrapper .ui-dialog-content {
    font-size: 12px
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#demo').dialog();
});
</script>


<div id="demo-wrapper">
    <div id="demo" title="sample dialog">blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that the dialog is modifying your HTML(check in browser console) ,so the selectors you are using is not working ,so try this style

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar, #demo.ui-dialog-content {
    font-size: 12px
}
```

[see here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gucu9u75/3/)

Answer (score 1):

To change size of title text you need to do this

```
<style>
#demo.ui-dialog-content {
  font-size: 12px;
}
span.ui-dialog-title {
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
```